Difficulties with MariaDB syntax using CTEs
I have the following query:
WITH intervals AS (
    SELECT rom_opening_interval.start,
           rom_opening_interval.end,
           priority,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC) AS rank
    FROM rom_opening_time
        INNER JOIN rom_opening_interval ON rom_opening_time.id = rom_opening_interval.opening_time_id
    WHERE rom_opening_time.start <= CURRENT_DATE
        AND (rom_opening_time.end >= CURRENT_DATE OR rom_opening_time.end IS NULL)
        AND days & 8 > 0
)
SELECT start, end, priority
FROM intervals
WHERE rank = 1;



The SELECT part of the CTE works totally fine. If I try to execute the whole query, I get a not further specified syntax error at line 11.
I'm using MariaDB 10.5 (10.5.23-MariaDB-1:10.5.23+maria~ubu2004) and other queries with CTE work fine as well, like the following one:
WITH test AS (
    SELECT start FROM rom_opening_interval
)
SELECT start FROM test;

Am I missing something here? And if yes, what?

I just found out that the problem probably has to do with the window function. The query works without the window function. Are window functions not allowed in CTEs?

Please post the full error. By the way what is AND days & 8 > 0 ?

@ErgestBasha It is just a generic error: "[42000][1064] (conn=24) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11"

You didn't answer my question. What do you mean by AND days & 8 > 0 ? Remove that line and try again your query

@ErgestBasha It's a bitwise comparison. Let's say we have two integers represented as binary numbers. 4 = 100 and 5 = 101. The binary and operator (&) will compare every bit and set the resulting bit to 1, if both bits are 1, or 0 otherwise. This is useful for comparing boolean data encoded in an Integer. For example in my case, every bit represents a weekday. Imagine the 8 replaced by another variable. If we want to find out if they have overlapping weekdays, that will be the case if the result is greater than 0.

@ErgestBasha In case you just wanted to know why I did that. It is just a test query. Later I want to replace the "8" by another parameter and find out if there are overlapping weekdays.

@ErgestBasha Removing the line results in the same error. But the query actually works if I leave out the window function. So I assume there must be some issue with that.

You have a lot of keywords as column names. What about SELECT cte.start, cte.end, cte.priority FROM intervals cte WHERE cte.rank = 1;

@topsail Good idea, but same error.

Its weird alright

Reserved keyword end not possible mask by table name(alias)? Use identifier as quoted with  .    SELECT intervals.start, intervals.end`, intervals.priority.

See (https://dbfiddle.uk/Hbb9FHPr) demo. End is reserved word. But not exist in list of keywords (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/). For example, you can use select table.desc from ... , but not select table.end ....

@ValNik end, rank , priority are not reserved keywords according to Reserved Words. https://dbfiddle.uk/FDJ98Pzc

Please give a [mcve] containing your tables and the query, because at the moment we cannot reproduce your error. Perhaps you have multiple queriesin a batch and forgot to terminate with ;

just guessing at which table some of the columns are in, but it works with 10.5.17: https://dbfiddle.uk/v4VGCYza    what exactly does select version(); show?

note rank is a reserved word in mysql but not mariadb https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/ which is curious..'The definitive list of reserved words for each version can be found by examining the sql/lex.h and sql/sql_yacc.yy files.'

@ysth The exact version is: 10.5.23-MariaDB-1:10.5.23+maria~ubu2004

Tryed to test it as is (with some dummy sample data) and it works fine on
10.5.17-MariaDB-1:10.5.17+maria~deb11 see the fiddle
You should realy post some of your sample data to get an exact answer. This works ok. You shouldn't use reserved words as column names or any names, though.
WITH
  rom_opening_time AS
    ( Select  101 as id, '2024-06-01' as start, '2024-06-02' as end, 1 as priority Union All
      Select  102 as id, '2024-06-03' as start, '2024-06-09' as end, 1 as priority Union All
      Select  103 as id, '2024-06-06' as start, '2024-06-14' as end, 1 as priority Union All
      Select  104 as id, '2024-06-10' as start, '2024-06-13' as end, 2 as priority Union All
      Select  105 as id, '2024-06-15' as start, null         as end, 2 as priority 
    ), 
  rom_opening_interval AS
    ( Select  1 as id, 101 as opening_time_id, '2024-06-01' as start, '2024-06-02' as end, 1 as days Union All
      Select  2 as id, 102 as opening_time_id, '2024-06-03' as start, '2024-06-09' as end, 6 as days Union All
      Select  3 as id, 103 as opening_time_id, '2024-06-06' as start, '2024-06-14' as end, 8 as days Union All
      Select  4 as id, 104 as opening_time_id, '2024-06-10' as start, '2024-06-13' as end, 7 as days Union All
      Select  5 as id, 105 as opening_time_id, '2024-06-15' as start, Null         as end, Null as days 
    ), 
  intervals AS 
    ( SELECT  rom_opening_interval.start,
              rom_opening_interval.end,
              priority,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC) AS rank
      FROM    rom_opening_time
      INNER JOIN rom_opening_interval ON rom_opening_time.id = rom_opening_interval.opening_time_id
      WHERE   rom_opening_time.start <= CURRENT_DATE
          AND (rom_opening_time.end >= CURRENT_DATE OR rom_opening_time.end IS NULL)
          AND days & 8 > 0
    )

--    S Q L : 
SELECT   start, end, priority
FROM     intervals
WHERE    rank = 1;

/*    R e s u l t :
start        end        priority
----------  ----------  --------
2024-06-06  2024-06-14         1  */

UPDATE:
Changed sample data to be like in your comment...
WITH
  rom_opening_time AS
    ( Select  101 as id, Cast('2024-06-01' as DATE) as start, Cast('2024-06-02' as DATE) as end, 1 as priority,  1    as days Union All
      Select  102 as id, Cast('2024-06-03' as DATE) as start, Cast('2024-06-09' as DATE) as end, 1 as priority,  6    as days Union All
      Select  103 as id, Cast('2024-06-06' as DATE) as start, Cast('2024-06-14' as DATE) as end, 1 as priority,  8    as days Union All
      Select  104 as id, Cast('2024-06-10' as DATE) as start, Cast('2024-06-13' as DATE) as end, 2 as priority,  7    as days Union All
      Select  105 as id, Cast('2024-06-15' as DATE) as start, Cast(null as DATE)         as end, 2 as priority,  Null as days 
    ), 
  rom_opening_interval AS
    ( Select  1 as id, 101 as opening_time_id, '01:00:00' as start, '01:10:00' as end Union All
      Select  2 as id, 102 as opening_time_id, '02:00:00' as start, '02:20:00' as end Union All
      Select  3 as id, 103 as opening_time_id, '03:00:00' as start, '03:30:00' as end Union All
      Select  4 as id, 104 as opening_time_id, '04:00:00' as start, '04:40:00' as end Union All
      Select  5 as id, 105 as opening_time_id, '05:00:00' as start, Null       as end 
    ),

... Still works ok ...
/*      R e s u l t :
start     end       priority
--------  --------  --------
03:00:00  03:30:00         1  */


Really strange. My tables are almost the same. Just that 'start' and 'end' in rom_opening_interval are time strings and 'days'  is on rom_opening_time.
My exact version is: 10.5.23-MariaDB-1:10.5.23+maria~ubu2004
I didn't use any reserved word, did I? start, end, rank and priority are not on this list: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/

I copied your code and executed it in my console. I still get the error. Thanks for taking the time helping me, I actually used a subquery approach now as a workaround.

try:
SELECT start, end, priority
FROM (
    SELECT
        rom_opening_interval.start,
        rom_opening_interval.end,
        priority,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC) AS rank
    FROM rom_opening_time
    INNER JOIN rom_opening_interval ON rom_opening_time.id = rom_opening_interval.opening_time_id
    WHERE rom_opening_time.start <= CURRENT_DATE
        AND (rom_opening_time.end >= CURRENT_DATE OR rom_opening_time.end IS NULL)
        AND days & 8 > 0
) AS intervals
WHERE rank = 1;


are you suggesting just using a subquery instead of the cte?  can you explain what problem that fixes?

Doesn't solve the exact question, but I actually gave up on it and used a subquery instead. Not this approach, though. I selected the maximum priority in the subquery and then selected the records with this priority in the outer query.

@OliverCoors feel free to edit answer and share your solution

Because it's too long for a comment, I'll post here what I did as a workaround. It's not an exact solution to the problem in the question, but delivers the wanted result by using a subquery:
SELECT rom_opening_interval.start AS start,
       rom_opening_interval.end AS end
FROM rom_opening_time
    INNER JOIN rom_opening_interval ON rom_opening_time.id = rom_opening_interval.opening_time_id
WHERE priority = (
    SELECT MAX(priority)
    FROM rom_opening_time
        INNER JOIN rom_opening_interval ON rom_opening_time.id = rom_opening_interval.opening_time_id
   WHERE rom_opening_time.start <= :date
      AND (rom_opening_time.end >= :date OR rom_opening_time.end IS NULL)
      AND days & :day = :day)
ORDER BY rom_opening_interval.start

